# Drupal_goto => POST $result as node Title

Tags: nodes

In order to be able to add a new node whenever a searched string is not found, I've added the following code in my theme directory as search-results.tpl.php.

```
<?php if ($search_results): ?>
  <h2><?php print t('Search results');?></h2>
  <ol class="search-results <?php print $module; ?>-results">
    <?php print $search_results; ?>
  </ol>
  <?php print $pager; ?>
<?php else: ?>
  <?php drupal_goto('node/add'); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After clearing the cache, this works fine.

Is it possible to POST the searched string to the node/add section? For example, if I am looking for "car" and the string is not found, I should be redirected to node/add  with "car" showed as node title.

Answer (score 2):

You add this line before your code:

`$search_term = arg(2);`

Send it in your drupal_goto, but you need to specify which content type to add (here i chose "article"):

`<?php drupal_goto('node/add/article', array('query'=>array('title'=>$search_term))); ?>`

And hook your node form in a custom module (here I chose content type "Article") :

```
function MY_MODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Find the content type of the node we are editing.
  $content_type = $form['#node']->type;
  if ($content_type == 'article') {
    if(isset($_GET['title'])){
      $form['title']['#default_value'] = $_GET['title'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should sanitize the string though.

Comment: Definitely, you need to perform more check than that, I just put the "required" one (isset). And there could also be some trouble with URL encoding for special characters, you should check that too.

Comment: Hi , just to be sure when creating a custom module, the name of the function has to be he same as the name of the module?

Comment: Yes, if your module name is "my_custom_module", then the function name should be "my_custom_module_form_node_form_alter"

Comment: Thanks , Do you think that i can change the 'node/add/article' by a variable defined trough a popup box? where I have for example the choice between 3 different node types.

Comment: I don't like popups so what I would do is redirecting to a custom page that you create, grab the URL argument "title" and build the links to your 3 content types adding the "title" argument to each link. Here is a link to create link in the proper drupal way and adding the title parameter: https://api.drupal.org/comment/13259#comment-13259

Answer (score 0):

There's a module for that: [Prepopulate](https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate).

Well, actually this module will only handle the link, prepopulating the fields you declare in the link. So you will not have to alter any form, but you will still have to prepare the correct link with drupal_goto().